# How check if a symfony server is still running?

Tags: symfony, symfony-cli

How to check if a started Symfony server is still running or not??

if I launch the server throw the command `symfony server:start`, I can guess (and check on a browser) that it is still running as long as the window of the command is still open.

If I launch the server to run in background, throw the command `symfony server:start -d`, I don't know, when I'm not able to access the server throw a browser, if it is something that went wrong within the server's config or code, due to different manipulations or it is that the server was even stopped for a specific reason ?

In a similar situation, I'd prefer to check first if the server is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check if the server is running by executing:

```
symfony server:status
```

To see all the commands in the `server` namespace, simply execute `symfony server`.

To see all the commands for the `symfony` CLI tool, simply execute:

```
symfony list
```